# Passing variable from one funtion to another

Tags: python

One thing I keep having trouble with in Python is passing information from one function to another, changing it and then passing it back to the original function to usefully use.  Take a look at this very basic example, trying to create a ping function that can be called by various other functions.

```
import subprocess
pingchk = 0

def pinger(pcName, pingchk):
    ping_out = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", pcName],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    if ('unreachable' in ping_out):
        print "Warning", "PC not responding 1."
        pingchk += 1
        return pingchk
    elif ('Request timed out.' in ping_out):
        print "Warning", "PC not responding 2."
        pingchk += 1
        print pingchk
        return pingchk
    elif ('Ping request could not find host' in ping_out):
        print "Warning", "PC not responding 3."
        pingchk += 2
        print pingchk
        return pingchk
    else:
        print "Machine available!"

def someFunction():
    pcName = raw_input("Please enter a pc name: ")
    pinger(pcName, pingchk)
    print pingchk
    if pingchk == 1:
        print "machine not switched on."
    elif pingchk == 2:
        print "machine name not recognized."
    else:
        print "success - machine on."

someFunction()
```

It's the `pingchk` bit that I'm struggling with. In this example `someFunction` is passing the `machineName` up to `pinger` to do the work, then I want `pinger` to pass the result back to `someFunction` to use. However, `someFunction` never re-reads the variable `pingchk` so always reads it as `0`.

What do I need to change to pass the results of `pinger` back to the originating function for use?

Comment: `pingchk = pinger(pcName, pinkchk)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks for the reply but if I try that it claims that it is being referenced before assignment...

Comment: @jonrsharpe maybe you missed it but `pinger(pcName,` **`pinkchk)`** uses the value of the global variable, by introducing assignment you make it a local variable that is references (as the argument to `pinger`) before it is assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonrsharpe suggested in a comment the way to go is simply to affect the returned value to the variable:

```
pingchk = pinger(pcName, pingchk)
```

There are only 2 caveats here:

- you have a branch that does not return anything (when you print *available*) so you will end with a None which may not be what you expect: consistently return 0 in that case or better move the return out of the if:

  ```
  def pinger(pcName, pingchk):
      ping_out = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", pcName],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
      if ('unreachable' in ping_out):
          print "Warning", "PC not responding 1."
          pingchk += 1
      elif ...
      else:
          print "Machine available!"
      return pingcheck
  ```
- as you affect the variable `pingcheck` in `somefunction` before is has been used, Python consideres that it is a local variable hiding the global one. You must declare it as global - if you really need it to be global:

  ```
  def someFunction():
      global pingchk
      pcName = raw_input("Please enter a pc name: ")
      pingchk = pinger(pcName, pingchk)
  ```

But if you have no real reason for pingcheck to be global, just let it be local:

```
    def someFunction():
        pcName = raw_input("Please enter a pc name: ")
        pingchk = pinger(pcName, 0)
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Just adding "pingchk = pinger(pcName, 0)" was all I needed. Creating the variable inside the function rather than outside. Thank-you so much!  Chris.

Answer (score 0):

To modify variables inside a function, pass them as list.

```
def ping(counter):
    counter[0] += 1  # lists are passed by reference, hence they can be changed in place

mycounter = [0]
ping(mycounter)
print mycounter[0]  # this will print 1
ping(mycounter)
print mycounter[0]  # this will print 2
```

Comment: Don't use a nuclear weapon to kill a fly... OP's code already return (almost allways...) the new value. jonrsharpe's suggestion is the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling a function in python, it returns a variable just like you are doing a basic math operation. For instance, if you do:

```
3*2
```

Your shell will return 6, but doesn't save this result. If you want to save it, just do:

```
x = 3*2
```

The same goes for your function `pinger`, when you call it from `someFunction`, you have to do:

```
pingchk = pinger(pcName, pingchk)
```

As `pingchk` otherwise is a local variable.

Another remark on your code: in `someFunction` you first call `pinger` with `pingchk` as an argument but it doesn't exist beforehand, therefore, your code won't turn.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Use a Global variable - Google will give you plenty of info and examples
2. My favorite, Put your variable in another module and import it.
   e.g.

   from commonstuff import pingcheck

Comment: how does putting it in a different module help?